# How elegantly make validation for the case when all fields in object are null?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I want to throw exception if all fields in object are null, but traditional way for checking on null looks not very smart. What can be another way to do this?

Comment: What is the `traditional` way?

Comment: be careful - if the primary key is automatically generated from a sequence, it won't be null when you create a new object.

Comment: traditional way is like in answer from Marcelo, it smells a little bit.

Comment: @Shikarn-O, What are the parameters? Can you show us a code snippet? There's absolutely nothing wrong with the "traditional" approach...

Comment: parameters doesn't matter, i think we can use something like hibernate validation. I think it's better to write some annotation and that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : This uses reflection (java.lang.reflect.Field)**

You could create a method within this object to return its valid state :

```
public boolean isValid() {
    boolean isValid = true;

    for (int i = 0; isValid && i < this.getClass().getFields().length; ++i) {
        if (this.getClass().getFields()[i].equals(null)) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

This way, the method is going to validate each and every field of the class so you don't need to modifiy the code whenever you add a new field to it.

HOWEVER,
the primary key cannot be null, so you have NOT to validate this field, or any NOTNULL field for that matter.

```
if (!field.getName().equals("aPrimaryKey_OR_aNotNullField")) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (a == null && b == null && c == null) 
    throw new AllFieldsAreNullException();
```

Comment: if you want some new field, you need to add new condition to if

Comment: @Shikarn-O You also have to add new field in your database table, new property in your entity, review your service layer, your DAOs and your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to write a generic method to analyse fields of an object, but it doesn't seem the clearest way of performing validation. I would perhaps be explicit for clarity's sake.